# Unable to run protractor script

Tags: test-automation-framework, protractor, uiautomation, jasmine

I'm not able to run my protractor tests. Getting the below error:

```
grunt cltest
Running "protractor:singlerun" (protractor) task
(node:26770) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[12:43:39] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:43:39] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[12:44:39] E/launcher - session not created: Chrome version must be >= 68.0.3440.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64)
[12:44:39] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome version must be >= 68.0.3440.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at /home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/home/delhivery/b2c-panel-automation/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:279:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:696:3)
[12:44:39] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
>> (node:26770) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
Warning: Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 199 Use --force to continue.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written in your log sample

```
Chrome version must be >= 68.0.3440.0
```

So you have to update you Chrome browser to meet version requirements.

**P.S.** - or downgrade your webdriver version.